# how to convert list of objects into specific data type

Tags: android, flutter, dart, iso

Possible solution if there is any ?
I lave a list of tabar like:

```
final tabList = [
      Icons.camera,
      "CHATS",
      "STATUS",
      "CALLS",
    ];
```

and i want to use this list like this way:

```
    TabBar(
tabs: tabList.map((e) => Tab()).toList();
```

and i want to set the value for icon and rest of them for text.

Comment: Don't put 2 data types in same list. Icons.camera and "CHATS". You can pass e to Tab() inside map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a list with two data types. Either you can create a list of type `String` or of type `IconData`. Optionally if you want both the properties together in a list you might try creating a class for accommodating the two types.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabItem {
  TabItem(this.name, this.icon);

  String name;
  IconData icon;
}

final tabList = [
  TabItem("Camera", Icons.camera),
  TabItem("Calls", Icons.phone),
  TabItem("Status", Icons.signal_wifi_statusbar_4_bar),
];

_getTabs() {
  return tabList.map((e) {
    return Tab(
      text: e.name,
      child: Icon(e.icon),
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `tabList` of type `List<dynamic>`, but that may cause issues.
Another solution would be to create an abstract class with child classes:

```
abstract class TabItem {}

class IconTab extends TabItem {
   final IconData icon;
   IconTab(this.icon);
}

class TitleTab extends TabItem {
   final String title;
   TitleTab(this.title);
}
```

and then set `tabList` of type `List<TabItem>`

```
final List<TabItem> tabList = [
  IconTab(Icons.camera),
  TitleTab("CHATS"),
  TitleTab("STATUS"),
  TitleTab("CALLS"),
];
```